# Shared storage for multiple VMs

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am looking for a solution to my issue. I would like to use one folder with fils for my VMs. 
I have tested a few solutions but always I have the same result. My shared folder is disconnected after every restart VM.

The problem is that Windows Server has credentials in Credential Manager.

I am trying to do this with net use, PowerShell and Cdmkey -
The easiest way to establish a persistent connection.

Does anybody has the same issue and found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Azure Files on my laptop it reconnects just fine after months of using it\rebooting\shutting down (i never hibernate). I think I was using net use\powershell and manually from explorer, all paths lead to the same outcome.

Another option - [Azure File Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-planning), quote:

> Use Azure File Sync to centralize your organization's file shares in
>   Azure Files, while keeping the flexibility, performance, and
>   compatibility of an on-premises file server. Azure File Sync
>   transforms Windows Server into a quick cache of your Azure file share.
>   You can use any protocol that's available on Windows Server to access
>   your data locally, including SMB, NFS, and FTPS. You can have as many
>   caches as you need across the world.

Comment: I am checking now Azure File Sync but there is something what I don't need to set up. 
I would like to use only one Shared disk but Azure File Sync has one server endpoint for every VM, not one for all. You have to register every VM and set up Path where you specify a path on VM like D:\Data.

Do you know what I mean?

Comment: yeah, because it a sync. azure files doesn't do that

Comment: I am looking for something that does do that.

Comment: you just said you dont need it. Azure Files doesnt need to sync files. it stores them in central location

Comment: I don't need it Azure files and Azure Sync because I am looking for a solution to my issue. It is clear. The only one shared storage for multiple VMs and that's it. You didn't answer on my question.

Comment: that is azure files

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: If you are talking about Storage account - Files. 
My shared folder is disconnected after every restart VM, Ir is not a persistent connection.

Comment: it is, like I said I'm using for literally years now, you misconfigured it

Comment: anyway, I haven't found solution yet

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at "persisting Azure File Share credentials in Windows" section in the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows. Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Yes, I have checked this solution. 

These commands are the same what you can find on Azure Portal. Home -> Storage accounts -> MyStorageName -> Files->File ; Connect:

There are PowerShell commands and Net use commands. My shared folder is disconnected after I reboot my VM.

Comment: Ah. You mentioned that Windows Server has credentials in Credential Manager. If that is the case, please try to simply persist the drive by using the following command and see how that works: Invoke-Expression -Command "cmdkey /add:storageaccount.file.core.windows.net /user:testuser /pass:<storagekey>"
New-PSDrive -Name G -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\foldername" -Persist